# Java class similar to c# system.diagnostics.process

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface

Is there a Java class that allows me to retrieve a process id information given the PID, instead of just returning the PID number? I know c# `system.diagnostics.process` can do it. for example given the pid return the process name.

Comment: The problem is that Java is intended to work on any operating system. Because not all operating systems may have this information available this feature may be missing in Java.

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23808662/2277482 which provides a way to get the process name provided the PID though it does seem like it will be quite limited in terms of more info other than name. Also take a look at JNA, myself never worked with it, but I have seen people get the PID using JNA and since it does give java native access I'd expect it to allow more.